# [Ljava.lang.String; when update the value of checkbox

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, checkbox

I made a web project from jsp and hibernate, on my from have a checkbox... I got no problem when insert the data but when update the data I got this `[Ljava.lang.String` in every first checkbox on my form and the value of my first checkbox doesn't store to database but the other checkbox work well

one more thing how to check the checkbox value from database??

this part of my jsp

```
<td><spring:message code="authorityRight" text="default text" /></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><fieldset id="menu_e">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="User" class="ceksmenu">User<br />
    <fieldset id="sub_menu_user_e">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="User1" class="ceksmuser">User1
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="User2" class="ceksmuser">User2
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="User3" class="ceksmuser">User3<br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="Monitoring" class="ceksmenu">Monitoring<br />
    <fieldset id="sub_menu_monitoring_e">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="Monitoring1" class="ceksmmonit">Monitoring1
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="Monitoring2" class="ceksmmonit">Monitoring2
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="Monitoring3" class="ceksmmonit">Monitoring3<br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="Parameter" class="ceksmenu">Parameter<br />
    <fieldset id="sub_menu_parameter_e">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="Parameter1" class="ceksmparam">Parameter1
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="Parameter2" class="ceksmparam">Parameter2
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="Parameter3" class="ceksmparam">Parameter3</fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    </td>
```

this is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.update').click(function() {
        var id_update = $(this).attr("id_update");
        var nama_authority = $(this).attr("nama_authority");
        var menu = $('input:checkbox[name=menu]').is(':checked');
        var sub_menu_user = $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_user]').is(':checked');
        var sub_menu_monitoring = $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_monitoring]').is(':checked');
        var sub_menu_parameter = $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_parameter]').is(':checked');

        $('#id_authority_e').val(id_update);
        $('#id_authority_l').val(id_update);
        $('#nama_authority_e').val(nama_authority);
        $('#menu_e').val(menu);
        $('#sub_menu_user_e').val(sub_menu_user);
        $('#sub_menu_monitoring_e').val(sub_menu_monitoring);
        $('#sub_menu_parameter_e').val(sub_menu_parameter);
    });
    $('.delete').click(function() {
       var id_delete = $(this).attr("id_delete");
    $('#id_authority_d').val(id_delete);
    });
    $('#example').dataTable({
    });
  });
</script>
```

and this is my controller

```
public class Operator {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/updateAuthority.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateAuthorityUser(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, 
                                            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String id_Authority = request.getParameter("id_authority");
        AuthorityUser authorityuser = authorityuserService.get(id_Authority);

        String nama = request.getParameter("nama_authority");
        String[] menu = request.getParameterValues("menu");
        String[] sb_user = request.getParameterValues("sub_menu_user");
        String[] sb_monitor = request.getParameterValues("sub_menu_monitoring");
        String[] sb_parameter = request.getParameterValues("sub_menu_parameter");

        authorityuser.setId_authority(id_Authority);
        authorityuser.setNama_authority(nama);
        authorityuser.setMenu(menu);
        authorityuser.setSub_menu_user(sb_user);
        authorityuser.setSub_menu_monitoring(sb_monitor);
        authorityuser.setSub_menu_parameter(sb_parameter);

        authorityuserService.update(authorityuser);
        model.addAttribute("successUpdate", "true");
        return listAuthorityUser(model);

    }
}
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Well, for a start your mark-up is invalid: ID attributes should be unique. I'm assuming you mean to create checkbox groups, in which case the name can stay the same, but not the ID. Further, you don't provide any code snippets or narrative around how you're reading / writing via Hibernate, so it's nigh-on impossible to help.

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String` is the internal name of the class representing `String[]`, which suggests that something in your code is receiving an array where it has been written to expect a single string.

Comment: @Ben I've been add some code, hope can help... Ian yeah, that is array, but when I edit the data just first of my checkbox like that the other of checkbox is ok...

Comment: OK, so there's some code: where do things go wrong for you? And like I said before, you have duplicate IDs in your mark-up, so that will give you some odd results.

Comment: @Ben I've try to use different ID but nothing data stored to database... my problem is my first checkbox doesn't store the value to database.. this happen just for my first checkbox, the other checkbox is ok..

Comment: 1. Examine and debug the relevant Javascript being used to set the value: sounds like something is awry there;
2. You mention that the other checkboxes work: do you mean that `request.getParameter()` is returning values for them?

Comment: @Ben I've edit my code, as you told me to use unique ID... that solve my "edit" problem ;)...may I ask you one more question?? how can I check the checkbox based on database, so when I'm going to "edit data" the checkbox was check

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String` isn't an error message. What *is* the error message?

Comment: @EJP there is no error message... just when I edit the data every first array data from my checkbox store as `[Ljava.lang.String`... but that was solved anyway...I just have one problem that how can I check the checkbox based on database, so when I'm going to "edit data" the checkbox was check... any idea??

Comment: So you passed an array of `String` where you evidently expected a `String.`